# Using ELMAH and URLRewritingNet Together

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, elmah, url-rewriting

I have ELMAH setup on my production server and it has done a fantastic job of letting me know about any niggles - as well as any creative SQL injection!

I've decided to introduce URl Rewriting and went for http://www.urlrewriting.net/ in the end.  It was nice and easy to setup and it's doing exactly what I want with the customer-facing site.

The problem is ELMAH. Because I've set the urlrewritingnet node in my config like so:

```
<urlrewritingnet
  rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true"
  contextItemsPrefix="QueryString"
  defaultPage = "default.aspx"
  defaultProvider="RegEx"
  xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07" >
```

...ELMAH likes to do this to it's axd links;

```
http://www.mydomain.com/elmah.axd/stylesheet/default.aspx
```

Does anyone have any idea how to either 
a) stop the re-writer following the .axd; or
b) add rules to the re-writer to get ELMAH to work

Any ideas?  I'm happy to hack about with the `httpHandlers`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved this, but not in the way I wanted too.  For the reference of others, I will provide a breakdown of what I did and the resources;

ELMAH: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/
URLRewritingNet: http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html

This was really the only available option to me: http://csharpin.blogspot.com/2009/03/using-urlrewritingnet-and-elmah.html, but I had untold difficulty to get the code into my existing architecture without other adverse affects. I did try adding rules to the ExternalRewrite.config (URL Rewrite) to ignore *.axd, but that didn't pan out either. I was getting all sorts of weird behaviour.

I then decided to use Health Monitoring: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031407-1.aspx instead of ELMAH. Sorry ELMAH :(

Health Monitoring was a snip to setup and then all I had to do was solve the nasty postback problem on rewritten URLs;

Health Monitoring web.config;

```
<!--he-mon-->
    <healthMonitoring enabled="true">
      <eventMappings>
        <clear />
        <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
      </eventMappings>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="healthMonitoringConnectionString" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823" buffer="false" name="SqlWebEventProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" />
        <add type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider" name="EmailWebEventProvider" from="xxx" to="yyy" bodyHeader="zzz" bodyFooter="000" buffer="false" />
      </providers>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="SqlWebEventProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" />
        <add name="All Errors Default Email" eventName="All Errors" provider="EmailWebEventProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" />
      </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
    <!--he-mon-->
```

Add the connection string to the `connectionString` node too.

To fix the rather nasty postback on URL rewritten strings, I tried ScottGu's suggestion; Handling ASP.NET PostBacks with URL Rewriting: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx, but I couldn't get that to work at all.

Starting to really regret getting into URL Rewriting, I finally added this to the one problematic page I had; `Me.Form.Action = Me.Request.RawUrl` within the `Page_Load` and it worked a treat.

I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but I hope it helps. I hope someone finds my information at least somewhat useful.

Comment: I've got a solution for you below, if you ever wish to revert back to UrlRewritingNet.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue - urlrewritingnet messing up my elmah - but found an answer here: http://markmail.org/message/ctbh6ozzqpe4qn6j#query:+page:1+mid:ctbh6ozzqpe4qn6j+state:results

Basically set defaultPage to empty like this:

Before (shortened):

```
<urlrewritingnet defaultPage="default.aspx" ... >
```

After (shortened):

```
<urlrewritingnet defaultPage="" ... >
```

Now all css styles work for Elmah.

Answer (score 3):

I [came up with a simpler solution](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2010/3/27/making-urlrewritingnet-ignore-urls-fix.aspx) if others are interested.

I just modify the source code directly and add in some basic logic to ignore specific rewrite rules.

Comment: I can't test this, but it looks pretty good actually. I am impressed. If I get a spare moment I might load it back onto a UrlRewritingNet and ELMAH project... Thanks. +1

Comment: My site right now directs every request through .NET, so when people visit http://intrepidstudios.com/tutorials/web%201001 URLRewriterNet will intercept it and serve "default.aspx" rather than index.html.

I added a rule to my config and voila, it works!

    <add name="Tutorials"
    virtualUrl="^~/tutorials/(.*)$"
    rewrite="None"
    />